# How to combine multiple commands output in the one varialble in shell script?

Tags: bash, sqlite, shell, sh

I'm using the following script to get the data of one of the variables from the database file

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlite3 pdu.db <<'END_SQL'
.timeout 2000
SELECT Variable_Value FROM Data Where Sr_No'7';
END_SQL
```

Now I wanted to store the output of the above commands in one variable. How we can store multiple commands output in one variable in the shell script?

Comment: Where are the multiple commands? There's just one bash command, `sqlite3`. It has multiple lines of input in the where-doc, but that doesn't create multiple commands.

Comment: What data are you getting? This just inserts and deletes, there's no `SELECT`.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

variable=$(sqlite3 pdu.db <<'END_SQL'
.timeout 2000
SELECT Variable_Value FROM Data Where Sr_No'7';
END_SQL
)

Comment: Edit the question.

Comment: You can stuff into a variable as much information as you like (since you can append to a variable). I would rather think of how the end effect should be represented: Just all the output pieces strung together, or with a separator? Or may be an array where each element contains the output of one command execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no restriction against putting a multiline command inside a command substitution.

```
variable=$(sqlite3 /var/www/dbs/ha.db <<'END_SQL'
.timeout 2000
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2;
DELETE FROM table2;
END_SQL
)
```